# Pandas dataframe create calculated column based on other column but dealing with None values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, calculated-columns

I am trying to calculate a column in pandas which categorises the row based on the values in other columns, however I am struggling to make my logic work where I have None values in the dataset.

I have a datafame like this which shows the value of record between two weeks.

| prior_week_value | current_week_value |
| --- | --- |
| None | 100 |
| 500 | 600 |
| 250 | 100 |

I want to be able to create a column which summarieses the difference between the two into 4 categories

- value increased (occurs when current_week_value > prior_week_value)
- value decreased (occurs when current_week_value < prior_week_value)
- value not changed (occurs when current_week_value == prior_week_value)
- new record (occurs when prior_week_value = None)

In this case it would look something like this

| prior_week_value | current_week_value | value_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | 100 | new record |
| 500 | 600 | value increased |
| 250 | 100 | value decreased |

I have tried to implement this with an if statement but have failed at the first hurdle at identifying the None values. All I get when I run the below code is the rows containing the None values evaluating as false and returning the test value in the else statement.

```
if df['prior_week_value'].isnull().all():
 df['value_category] = 'new record'
else:
 df['value_category] = 'test'
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Umar.H for your help - I made a small tweak and it worked, here is the code:

```
s = df['prior_week_value'] # this is the change i made to the code provided

cond = [
    s.isnull(),
    df['current_week_value'] > s,
    df['current_week_value'] < s,
    df['current_week_value'] == s,
]

results = ['new_record', 'value_increased', 'value_decreased', 'no_change']

df['value_category'] = np.select(cond, results)
```